# The best way to connect Hybrid stepper motor Simpower model to Simmechanics v2 in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, simmechanics, simpowersystems

I need to connect a hybrid stepper motor model to a rotative joint in a 2nd generation Simmechanics model build by myself. I connected the output angle of the stepper model to the actuation - motion input, letting the joit module to calculate the load torque. Then I give this load torque to the load torque input of the stepper model. Do you think that this can be accurate or not? Which is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a question of engineering practices

Comment: @AnderBiguri Actually, it isn't. It's about how to connect blocks in Simulink.

Comment: This is a valid approach. However, it is generally better practice to actuate SimMechanics with force/torque and feed back position/velocity to SimPowerSystems. The [Stepper Motor block](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/steppermotor.html) only accepts a load torque input so your approach is the only feasible one.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach will be to connect the step angle output of the stepper motor to the joint actuator angle input. Then estimate the total inertia of the Simmechanics model you are trying to control with the joint. add an ideal  inertia rotation element to the stepper R port of which the value is equal to the  total inertia. please use this approach only if the models inertia is constant